# JQuery add elements on radiobutton selection

Tags: jquery

I want to add elements dynamically to a Page on selection of a particular RadioButton

Comment: and what should we do with that?

Comment: Hi sudip, you haven't asked a real question here, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for how to write a good question that will get a some good answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#your_radio").bind('click', function(){
    $("#your_div").html('your content');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM Insertion methods (see http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) in an event handler for a http://api.jquery.com/select/ event against the radio button option or http://api.jquery.com/change/ event against the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

It goes like this ex.

```
$('#checkboxID').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked') {
        // add new element here
    } else {
        // if u need you can remove this element here
    }
});
```

it will add element only when clicked to check, also by using else you can toggle through different elements for different selections